# Why did @TestConfiguration not create a bean for my test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

My service

```
@Service
public class StripeServiceImpl implements StripeService {
    @Override
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

My test

```
public class StripeServiceTests {
    @Autowired
    StripeService stripeService;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public StripeService employeeService() {
            return new StripeServiceImpl();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void findCustomerByEmail_customerExists_returnCustomer() {
        assertThat(stripeService.getCustomerId()).isEqualTo(2);
    }   

}
```

The error: java.lang.NullPointerException. I had checked and the stripeService is actually null.

Comment: check whether you have @Service annotation in StripeServiceImpl class

Comment: Yes, of course. My app still run properly. I edited my question already.

Comment: try to remove TestConfig class and check. no need to define a bean again if you already autowired.

Comment: Maybe there is a `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` (JUnit 4) or `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` (JUnit 5) missing at the test class.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are autowiring you need an applicationcontext so that Spring can manage the bean and then can get injected in your class. Therefore you are missing an annotation to create the applicationcontext for your testclass.

I have updated your code and it works now(with junit 5 on your classpath). In the case dat you are using junit 4 it should be `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` instead of `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class StripeServiceTests {
    @Autowired
    StripeService stripeService;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public StripeService employeeService() {
            return new StripeServiceImpl();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void findCustomerByEmail_customerExists_returnCustomer() {
        assertThat(stripeService.getCustomerId()).isEqualTo(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, your solution worked but I hope to use @TestConfiguration to instantiate just a bean instead of bring up whole application context. I'll give a vote instead of marking answer, thank you.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an extra annotation. You can annotate your class with @ContextConfiguration and pass the classes attribute.